# NameError when importing from module even if module is loaded

Tags: python

I have created a module
`RL_func` containing some functions.

When I load the module in my main script it raised a `NameError` for numpy which I use in the imported functions. Both files are in the same folder.

```
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import RL_func
    ...
    RL_func.print_policy(pi, P, action_symbols=('<', '>'), n_cols=7)
```

Error Message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
g:\Coding\reinforcement learning\test.py in <module>
     13     0:RIGHT, 1:RIGHT, 2:RIGHT, 3:RIGHT, 4:RIGHT, 5:RIGHT, 6:RIGHT
     14 }[s]
---> 15 RL_func.print_policy(pi, P, action_symbols=('<', '>'), n_cols=7)

g:\Coding\reinforcement learning\RL_func.py in print_policy(pi, P, action_symbols, n_cols, title)
     28         a = pi(s)
     29         print("| ", end="")
---> 30         if np.all([done for action in P[s].values() for _, _, _, done in action]):
     31             print("".rjust(9), end=" ")
     32         else:

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I don't understand why this happens with numpy clearly being defined before importing the functions.

Also tried:

```
from RL_func import print_policy
```

EDIT:
Importing the modules the functions require in `RL_func` solved the problem.

Comment: The module needs to import whatever other modules it needs, itself.  Importing them in your main script doesn't affect the module at all.

Comment: Yeah. That did it. Thanks

Comment: please write the solution as an answer despite mentioning it in question!

Answer (score 0):

Importing the modules the functions require in `RL_func` solved the problem.